# Using iOS Simulator to emulate iPad 1

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

One of my customers is experiencing terrible slow downs only on the iPad 1 device. Is there any way of getting the iOS Simulator to emulate the performance/hardware of the original iPad?

I would rather not have to go out and buy an iPad one as iOS 6 won't support it this autumn.

The app runs fine on the iPad 2 and 3. I have tested using the allocations and activity instruments.

Any ideas? Thanks again. The OS is 5.1.1 and the App was compiled with XCode 4.4.1.

Comment: Keep in mind there is a big difference between simulation and emulation, and Apple supplies you with a simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the simulator is what it says, a simulator, and as such will run as fast as it can on whichever computer you're using. You'll probably need to put delaying code into your run loops to simulate the slowness of the iPad 1, but maybe your client needs to be aware that the iPad 1 is much slower than the newer models - there are certainly some (particularly graphic intensive) operations which will struggle - you may find you need to adapt the user experience according the the device being used (Apple don't encourage this - they prefer you to check the iOS version - but there are several questions on SO which could help you here).

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I think we might just need to buy an iPad one to get round this issue.

Comment: I had loads of problems with an iPad 1 on an old project - we ended up with seriously cut-down graphical functionality for it in the end.

Comment: I fins it amazing that the iPad 1 is only 2 years old, yet some of the businesses that bought them in 2010 are only just starting to use them.